# Drupal: run custom code when a form is submitted

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

how can I run specific code when a form is submitted in Drupal ?

I'm using hook_form_alter to edit the form, but I actually need to collect the data inserted by user and run code when the user click on "Save / Register" etc

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add callbacks to the submit array. It goes something like this:

```
function myform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'some_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mycallback';
  }
}

function mycallback(&$form, &$form_state) {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following function:

```
function myform_form_submit($form_id, $form_values){ 
        print_r($form_values);
        // custom code 
 }
```

worked for me. Hope it helps :)